# why TagHelper not active?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Welcome everyone
I'm using visual studion 2022 with asp.net core 7 now, I'm building my first app with sql server, everything is done but when I run the index page the data is shown but the edit view, create and delete is not active it shows as text!! what's the problem?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xoTJ.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVVd1.png)
ViewImports file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWDyt.png)

Comment: Can you share the rendered html source code (in the browser: View Page Source)?

Comment: yes ... iam editing my question and add the  Page Source

Comment: sir and in edit or create page the button not generate the data in database just reload without save !!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. In Views Folder, right click and add new folder with the name of **Shared**
2. In Shared folder add new item Razor View Imports: _ViewImports.cshtml
3. In _ViewImport.cshtml, add the following line:

```
    @addTagHelper "*,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"
```

4.if you use Razor Pages, put _ViewImports in the pages folder in addition to Views Folder

Comment: this file already in my project .. you can se the image in my question aim updating

Comment: if you use Razor Pages, have you put _ViewImports in the pages folder in addition to Views Folder?

Comment: thank you very very very match .. done copy this file in my folder for view another pages and the page is run and execute every thing

Comment: I edited the answer and added the above comment for future use. if you think, it is right answer, you can accept the answer.thanks.

Comment: yes this is right answer thanx